# Find all integer triples $(a,b,c)$ such that the equation $2a^2 + b^2 = 5c^2$ holds. Is $(0, 0, 0)$ the only solution to this equation?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

First I realized that $2a^2 + b^2\equiv 0\pmod 5$, so I worked out that $2a^2\equiv 0\pmod 5$ and $b^2\equiv 0\pmod 5$, which implied that $a$ and $b$ (and after a few steps $c$, too) are multiples of 5. From this point on I continued and eventually came across a contradiction, which led to $(0, 0, 0)$ being the only possible integer triple, which satisfies the equation above.

Can someone confirm that this is true or give insight on how to find the other triples, if there exists other ones.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The method you used is commonly known as [proof by infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent).

Comment: I think we can also use mod 4 and then mod 8 to arrive at a contradiction in quite a similar way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $a$, we know $a^2 \equiv 0,1,$ or $4 \mod 5$. Then $2a^2 \equiv 0,2,$ or $3 \mod 5$ and $b^2 \equiv 0,1,$ or $4 \mod 5$. When could their sum equal $0 \mod 5$ as you pointed out it must?

Comment: when a and b are multiples of 5

Comment: Right. And now see if  you find can that $5 | c^2$ and thus that $5|c$, because if you can, then you can factor out the common 5 to find a whole new equation $10x^2+y^2=5z^2$, where $x \le a, y \le b, z \le c$, in which case you could start again...and find a contradiction by infinite descent.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems correct. More formally, for a non-trivial (that is, not $(0, 0, 0)$) solution, by dividing $a$, $b$, and $c$ by $\text{gcd}(a, b, c)$, we may assume that $\text{gcd}(a, b, c) = 1$. Then you show that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all multiples of 5. This is a contradiction.